# rails mailer: email not being delivered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, mailer

I am trying to have Rails send emails. It seems to work and I dont get any errors on my local server, however I cannot receive any emails. Everything seems to be working fine, just cause there are no errors thrown, however the emails are not being delivered.

application_mailer.rb

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'test@example.com'
  layout 'send_message'
end
```

mailer.rb

```
class Mailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: "test@example.com"
  layout 'send_message'

 def send_message
    mail(to: 'test_email@test.com', subject: 'Sample Email')do |format|
      format.html { render layout: 'send_message' }
      format.text
    end
  end
end
```

development.rb

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
```

application.rb

I've tried this a couple of different ways, one way with no changes to this file and another way with the changes just below

```
    config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000'    }
    config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
    config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,
    :address => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    :port => '25',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :domain => 'gmail.com',
    :user_name => 'my_gmail_email@gmail.com',
    :password => 'password'
  }
```

where the email is sent in my controller

```
  def create

    @collected_email = CollectedEmail.new(collected_email_params)

    if @collected_email.save
      Mailer.send_message.deliver_now
      render json: @collected_email, status: :created, location: @collected_email
    else
      render json: @collected_email.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

I have two views views/layouts and views/mailer. I'm not sure why this is necessary but if I remove one the mailer does not work. In each of the view folders I have a send_message.html.erb and a send_message.text.erb, they are very simple and they are exactly the same between each view folder.

the send_message.text.erb

```
tester123
```

the send_message.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to example.com</h1>
    <p>
      You have successfully signed up to example.com,
      your username is:<br>
    </p>
    <p>
      To login to the site, just follow this link.
    </p>
    <p>Thanks for joining and have a great day!</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's my server logs for one  entry.

```
Started POST "/collected_emails" for ::1 at 2015-08-06 21:09:22 -0400
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".*   FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by CollectedEmailsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"collected_email"=>{"email"=>"afsdlkjafs@asdfljk.cc"}}
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  CollectedEmail Exists (0.9ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "collected_emails"   WHERE ("collected_emails"."email" = 'afsdlkjafs@asdfljk.cc' AND    "collected_emails"."email" = 'afsdlkjafs@asdfljk.cc') LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "collected_emails" ("email", "created_at",    "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["email",   "afsdlkjafs@asdfljk.cc"], ["created_at", "2015-08-07 01:09:22.533596"],    ["updated_at", "2015-08-07 01:09:22.533596"]]
   (14.9ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered mailer/send_message.html.erb within layouts/send_message (2.2ms)
  Rendered mailer/send_message.text.erb within layouts/send_message (0.6ms)

Mailer#send_message: processed outbound mail in 426.4ms 

Sent mail to testeremail@email.com (30020.6ms)
Date: Thu, 06 Aug 2015 21:09:23 -0400
From: test@example.com
To: testeremail@email.com
Message-ID: <55c405439564_42a63fd0b5b8f02c676b8@William-Sargents-MacBook-   Pro.local.mail>
Subject: Sample Email
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="--==_mimepart_55c4054363e0_42a63fd0b5b8f02c67578";
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


----==_mimepart_55c4054363e0_42a63fd0b5b8f02c67578
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

tester123

----==_mimepart_55c4054363e0_42a63fd0b5b8f02c67578
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to example.com</h1>
    <p>
      You have successfully signed up to example.com,
      your username is:<br>
    </p>
    <p>
      To login to the site, just follow this link.
    </p>
    <p>Thanks for joining and have a great day!</p>
  </body>
</html>

----==_mimepart_55c4054363e0_42a63fd0b5b8f02c67578--

Completed 201 Created in 30677ms (Views: 1.4ms | ActiveRecord: 19.4ms)
```

Comment: config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false why is this  false if you're looking to raise errors on development?

Comment: Try `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :file` to see if the mail is generated in `tmp/mails/`